# Populate bi-dimensional array with data inside for-loop

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm pretty new to C# and I have to go through some data, compute the sum of each of them and save it into an array and also save the name of it.

So, for an input like this:

```
name1 name2 name3 name4
1       1     3      0
0       0     4      5
0       0     0      0
```

I must have as result an array like this:

```
[["name1", 1], ["name2", 1], ["name3", 7], ["name4", 5]]
```

Until so far I managed to compute the sums and save them into the array, the problem is when I want to add the name of them.

This is my code:

```
int m = result.Sites.Count;
double[] sum = new double[result.Sites.Count];
for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < result.Sites[i].Actual.Count; j++)
    {
        sum[i] += (double)result.Sites[i].Actual[j];
    }

}
```

It works fine for computing the sum.

The name of each Site is in `result.Sites[i].SiteName`.

I tried it like this:

```
double[][] sum = new double[result.Sites.Count];
for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < result.Sites[i].Actual.Count; j++)
    {
        sum[i][1] += (double)result.Sites[i].Actual[j];
    }
    sum[i][0] = result.Sites[i].SiteName;

}
```

It says that it cannot convert string to double. I don't know if it is possible to have 2 types of data inside the same array or should I use an object or something else I don't know.

Do you see any good solution to this?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could give us a [mcve] with sample inputs specified in it. _Also please specify the expected output you want to receive._

Comment: Try considering creating a class with proper properties instead of array.

Comment: There is a generic class ```Dictionary<string,int>```, you might use for storing and assigning. Maybe combine it with a ```List<>``` .

Comment: Try List<KeyValuePair<string,double>>

Answer (score 1):

It is a lot simpler if you define an object to store your info and then use a bit of Linq to remove the inner loop.

```
public class SiteData
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public double Total {get;set;}
}
....

List<SiteData> summary = new List<SiteData>()
for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
{
    SiteData aSite = new SiteData();
    aSite.Name = result.Sites[i].SiteName;
    aSite.Total = result.Sites[i].Actual.Sum();
    summary.Add(aSite);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't have an array with two types. You need to use a class instead:

```
public class SiteInfo
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public double Sum {get;set;}
}

SiteInfo[] sum = new SiteInfo[result.Sites.Count];
for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
{
    SiteInfo si = new SiteInfo();
    for (int j = 0; j < result.Sites[i].Actual.Count; j++)
    {
        si.Sum += (double)result.Sites[i].Actual[j];
    }
    si.Name = result.Sites[i].SiteName;

    sum[i] = si;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `class`, or some of the available pair types like [`KeyValuePair`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5tbh8a42) or [`Tuple`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268536).
With LINQ extensions it can be something like:

```
//using System.Linq;                                         // at the top of the file
//using KVP = System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string, double>;

KVP[] sums = result.Sites.Select(s => new KVP(s.SiteName, s.Actual.Sum())).ToArray();
// or List<KVP> sums = result.Sites.ConvertAll(s => new KVP(s.SiteName, s.Actual.Sum()));
```

or convert to `Dictionary<string, double>` if the names are unique:

```
var sums = result.Sites.ToDictionary(s => s.SiteName, s => s.Actual.Sum());
```

Answer (score -1):

declare your variables as 'object' type so that you can convert them from one to another as long as the data inside the object variable is compatible with your convertion type.